# Joing lists with anonymous columns from dynamic pivot

Tags: c#, linq, join, dynamic, pivot

I have two lists that share a common field. I would like to join the lists on the common field however, one of the lists comes from a SQL dynamic pivot so all of the column names from that list, except for the linking field have unknown column names. My question is how do I find those column names so I can create the new list?

**Example**

```
class Student 
{
 int StudentID {get; set;}
 string FirstName {get; set;}
 string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

**studentCollection** is a collection of Students

I use the `class ReportRanking` here as an example. It is a `dynamic` class that is returned from a stored procedure that makes use of a dynamic pivot. So I do not know the column names ahead of time. I am using `TestScore-1`, `TestScore-2`, etc .. as placeholders to show what is returned. The column names will contain the name of the test the student took. The value in the column will be the score they received.

```
class StudentTestScores
{
 int StudentID {get; set;}
 int TestScore-1 {get; set;}
 int TestScore-2 {get; set;}
 int TestScore-3 {get; set;}
 ...
}
```

**testResultCollection** is a collection of StudentScores.

```
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+
| StudentId | History | Algebra | Geometry | Biology |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|     1     |    88   |    96    |    87    |    91   |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+
|     2     |    92   |    75    |    88    |    74   |
+-----------+---------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Because the results come from a dynamic pivot I do not know at compile-time what the names of the columns in StudentTestScores are. They represent the name of the test taken by the student. How do I reference the column name so I can combine the lists into a new composite list?

```
var testResults = from student in studentCollection 
                    join testResult in testResultCollection 
                      on student.StudentId equals testResult.StudentId 
                    select new {
                      student.StudentId,
                      student.FirstName,
                      student.LastName,
                      testResult.XXXXXXX // Not sure how to reference the test scores
                      ...
                    }
```

This is what I need to end up with ...

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| StudentId | FirstName | LastName | History | Algebra | Geometry | Biology |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|     1     | Bob       | Smith    |    88   |    96   |    87    |    91   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|     2     | Sally     | Jenkins  |    92   |    75   |    88    |    74   |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: What is the end goal? You want serialize result to json or something like that?

Comment: The end goal would be to a have a single collection that I could iterate over and create a report from (Excel, CSV, etc..)

Comment: Since you dont know properties at compile time, that will be list of unknown types (objects, dynamic, etc). Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, because I can iterate over the collection at that point. Once I get them together than I have no issue with looping over the collection to build the column headers and grab the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would combine your objects into one `ExpandoObject`, and return it as dynamic. That way you can access it's properties as usual (since it's dynamic) and any reflection code (like serialization to json\csv) will also be able to explore it's properties as usual. Here is the code:

```
class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class StudentTestScores {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int History { get; set; }
    public int Algebra { get; set; }
    public int Geometry { get; set; }
    public int Biology { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var studentCollection = new List<Student>(new [] {
        new Student() {StudentId = 1, FirstName = "Test", LastName = "Test"}, 
    });
    var testResultCollection = new List<StudentTestScores>(new [] {
        new StudentTestScores() {StudentId = 1, Algebra = 2, Biology = 5, Geometry = 3}, 
    });
    var testResults = from student in studentCollection
                      join testResult in testResultCollection
                        on student.StudentId equals testResult.StudentId
                      select Combine(student, testResult);
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testResults));
    // outputs [{"StudentId":1,"FirstName":"Test","LastName":"Test","History":0,"Algebra":2,"Geometry":3,"Biology":5}]
    Console.ReadKey();
}



static dynamic Combine(params object[] objects) {            
    var exp = (IDictionary<string, object>) new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (var o in objects) {
        var dict = o as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (dict != null) {
            foreach (var prop in dict) {
                if (!exp.ContainsKey(prop.Key)) {
                    exp.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
                } 
            }
        }
        else {
            foreach (var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)) {
                if (prop.CanRead && !exp.ContainsKey(prop.Name)) {
                    exp.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(o));
                }
            }
        }
    }            
    return exp;
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question I do know know what the column names could be for the test results. They could be (History, Math, Spelling) or (Chemistry, Biology, Math) or (Basket Weaving, Art, Music) or any other combination.

Comment: @webworm but code in answer does not care about names. Those names there are just for example.

Comment: However, `select Combine(student, testResult)` may be just what I needed. I was not aware of `combine`. I see what your saying about the names now.

Comment: When I try this locally I get `[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]` for the console output

Comment: Can you post test data you use? With test data from answer it works fine.

Comment: Here is an example from the first row when looking at the collection returned by Dapper. `[0] {{DapperRow, StudentID = '634524', HISTORY = '1', BIOLOGY = '4', ALGEBRA = '16', GEOMETRY = '9', SPANISH = '12', FRENCH = '14', HEALTH = '8', COOKING = '3', ANCIENTSTUDIES = '10', WRITING = '6', MECHANICS = '7', MODELING = '11', ELECTRONICS = '2', PROGRAMMING = '5', HARDWARE = '15', DATABASES = '13'}} object {Dapper.SqlMapper.DapperRow}`

Comment: As I step through the Combine method it is never entering into the contents of the `foreach loop`. It never hits `if (prop.CanRead && !exp.ContainsKey(prop.Name))`

Comment: Would you be able to demonstrate that by modifying the example? If you can and it works the bounty is yours! Sorry I did not mention Dapper in the original post. I was trying to simplify the example as much as possible. Guess I went too far.

Comment: Ok I've modified answer to take this into account.

Comment: That works! Gives me the data I need. Thanks so much for the example. I need to wait 16 hours to assign the bounty

Answer (score 2):

I would use reflection to get the value if you do not know the naming of what the class property would be till run time.

```
public class Student
  {
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }

  public class StudentTestScores
  {
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int TestScoreGen {get; set;}
  }

  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var studentCollection = new List<Student> { new Student { StudentID = 1, FirstName = "Brett", LastName = "X" }, new Student { StudentID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Y" } };
      var testResultCollection = new List<StudentTestScores> { new StudentTestScores { StudentID = 1, TestScoreGen = 94 }, new StudentTestScores { StudentID = 2, TestScoreGen = 86 } };
      var props = testResultCollection.First().GetType().GetProperties();

      //Check my properties
      props.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

      var testResults = from student in studentCollection
                        join testResult in testResultCollection
                          on student.StudentID equals testResult.StudentID
                        select new
                        {
                          student.StudentID,
                          student.FirstName,
                          student.LastName,
                          resultName = testResult.GetType().GetProperty(props[1].Name),
                          resultValue = testResult.GetType().GetProperty(props[1].Name).GetValue(testResult, null)
                        };

      testResults.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.StudentID} {x.FirstName} {x.LastName} {x.resultName} {x.resultValue}"));

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Update 11-22

You may have issues if a property does not exist.  In this case reflection blows up because nothing is there.  This would be the equivalent of a left join in SQL.  You may be joining to something that is sometimes there, sometimes not.  In which case you merely need to know how to handle such a thing.  I have updated the above example of how to synthesize this.  Basically I am seeing that I have 2 or more properties, of which I do not.  I then choose what to do if I do not have that with a ternary operator.  Ternary operators are nice in my opinion for direct assignment for an if, then, else.

```
public class Student
  {
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }

  public class StudentTestScores
  {
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    //public int TestScoreGen {get; set;}
  }

  class Program
  {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var studentCollection = new List<Student> { new Student { StudentID = 1, FirstName = "Brett", LastName = "X" }, new Student { StudentID = 2, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Y" } };
      //var testResultCollection = new List<StudentTestScores> { new StudentTestScores { StudentID = 1, TestScoreGen = 94 }, new StudentTestScores { StudentID = 2, TestScoreGen = 86 } };
      var testResultCollection = new List<StudentTestScores> { new StudentTestScores { StudentID = 1 }, new StudentTestScores { StudentID = 2 } };
      var props = testResultCollection.First().GetType().GetProperties();

      //Check my properties
      props.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

      var testResults = from student in studentCollection
                        join testResult in testResultCollection
                          on student.StudentID equals testResult.StudentID
                        select new
                        {
                          student.StudentID,
                          student.FirstName,
                          student.LastName,
                          resultName = props.Count() > 1 ? testResult.GetType().GetProperty(props[1]?.Name)?.ToString() : "Nothing",
                          result = props.Count() > 1 ? testResult.GetType().GetProperty(props[1]?.Name).GetValue(testResult, null) : "0"
                        };

      testResults.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.StudentID} {x.FirstName} {x.LastName} {x.resultName} {x.result}"));

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I see how you are using reflection to obtain the score, but how would I grab the header of the score column which would contain the class name (`History`, `Algebra`, `Geometry`, and `Biology`)?

Comment: I am confused, if you know the name you would just use 'testResult.History' or 'testResult.Algebra'.  If you DO NOT know the name but know the position it comes in a class POCO object you would do props[1] for the 2nd position after the StudentID and so on.  If you just want to echo 'History' or 'Algebra' along with their value.  That is pretty simple.  Let me update my answer and you can see.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion ... I DO NOT KNOW the names of the classes at compile-time (History, Algebra, Biology, tec..), but I do know the position in the POCO object as I know how many there will be and the order is not important.

Comment: Than my updated example should work for you if you just want to see the name along with the value as well.

Comment: Getting the following error when trying this `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException : Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

Comment: Can you edit your example? The code you have there does not work.

Comment: Sure updated.  I was wrong saying to use a null coalescing operator as really it will blow up in the indexing anyways.  You need a ternary operator for assignment.

Comment: Thanks! If it works I will be more than happy to assign the bounty to you. Working on a Production issue at the moment but I will try it later this afternoon.

Comment: `testResultCollection.First().GetType()` results in NULL. This is where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: No prob, also keep in mind I am assigning the schema for the observation of reflection with the first object in your collection.  If you need 'props' variable to be something where the 2nd or 3rd object may be different types, you would need to iterate through the collection and determine the object with the most properties as the winner.  Provided of course that the other ones obey the schema but are only missing some properties.  Else if you have one object of (string, string, int) and then next is (string, object, datetime, string, etc..), it would blow up.

Comment: My updated example in the answer works on my box as it should not be calling that bit of code UNLESS the properties have more than 2 types, which in the example they never will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128736/discussion-between-webworm-and-djangojazz).